# A polite way to let people go in front of you in a checkout queue

Tags: politeness

How can you politely tell someone standing behind you in a checkout queue that they can go in front of you?

For example if they have only 1 or 2 items in their trolley and mine is full, or if I forgot something and have to go back to get it.

Comment: Sometimes in this situation you need not even speak: you can just smile and gesture that they move ahead of you.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's that awkward situation when you have a battle to see who is the most courteous - "you can go", "no no you go", "no really you go", etc etc ;)

Comment: @JamesWirth - Until the third person in line says "Enough! *I'll* go."

Comment: "Please go ahead. (I have something to pick up)"

Comment: ...or just "go ahead": simple, literal and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

We often phrase things as questions to make an indirect/polite request or suggestion, so you could say

> Why don't you go ahead of me?

You could then explain why: they have only two items and your trolley (called a 'cart' in the USA), or you need to go back and get more items.

You can use questions in similar ways:

> Why don't you do your math homework before going to the mall?

This is an extremely polite way of saying

> You should (or need to) do your math homework before you go to the mall.